# How to write the depth() method without the Node inside the parameter?

Tags: java, binary-tree, depth

There is an assignment where we have to modify the Binary Tree with the following methods. I was able to write all the methods to work, including the depth() method. However, as I read the question carefully I noticed that I wrote this method with a node inside the parameters instead of a variable (in this case its int key).

Here is my code:

```
    public int getDepth(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int leftSubtreeDepth = getDepth(node.leftChild);
        int rightSubtreeDepth = getDepth(node.rightChild);

        if (leftSubtreeDepth > rightSubtreeDepth) {
            return (leftSubtreeDepth + 1);
        } else {
            return (rightSubtreeDepth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is correct when I used this code. However, now that I know that I have to write the depth method with an int key variable (aka. public int getDepth(int key) ), is there anything I can do to change this code up? I hope it's just a small change/fix since it took me a while to write this code.

Comment: What other methods are available? Is there a global variable which will give access to the binary tree from this method? If 'key' is given as input, what is the `getDepth` method supposed to compute?

Comment: The following methods that are in my code are:
1. void insert(int id, double dd)
2. Node find(int key) 
3. boolean delete(int key)
4. int size()
5. int depth(int key)
6. void removeLeaves()
7. int rightMinValue()
8. int leftMaxValue()
9. int maximum()
10. int minimum()
11. void preOrder()
12. void inOrder()
13. void postOrder()

Comment: The getDepth method is supposed to show how many levels appeared in the tree

Comment: Does it mean return the level at which the node with given key is?

Comment: My mistake. The depth of a node is the length of the path. The height if the deepest node. 

I think the method I wrote is just finding the max depth instead

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-level-of-a-node-in-a-binary-tree/

Comment: I can see what the code is saying, but is that the only way to write the depth() method? Will it be possible if I don't have to write the Node inside the parameter and just write int key?

Comment: If you want to pass a key to the method, simply call `find(key)` inside the method to get the Node.